# ubuntu dock icon - choose window on click

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm used to great windows bar, and when i hover or click, i see every window in the group (like 2 chrome instances).
But when I click on the icon in Ubuntu, I see the main window, and if I want another one I have to click Right mouse button, the choose "all windows" and finally click on the window that I want to choose.

Can I change it, so it's more friendly and straightforward?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The following command should do the trick for you to always show a preview when multiple windows are opened from a given application:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I change it, so it's more friendly and straightforward?

More or less, yes to some extent.

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Virtual Machine) and I have configured the Dock to my liking (Chrome and All).

The Dock is much simpler than the Windows Task Bar and task bar settings, and so does not accomplish as much.

I have gone through the Ubuntu Settings for Dock. The Dock options do not provide for expansive right click options.

For a given App (like Chrome) (not certain about All APPS), if you have multiple Chrome windows open, you can right click on Chrome in the Dock and Quit 2 (or 3, ...) windows; or you can right click and Open a new window.

What you can do is shown on the Right Click in the Dock for a specific App.

So what you want can be done, but it is not like Windows.

So (natively) you can get a workable behavior, just not like Windows 10 or 11.

[image: Ubuntu Dock Behavior]